# Bad credentials for bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm getting `Bad credentials for bucket` trying to mount a GCS bucket using gcsfuse. What I've done:

- Created a bucket "mac-gcs-fuse"
- Created a service account in the same project with all storage permissions
- Run the following command

```
gcsfuse --key-file=/Users/tiagogouvea/Keys/gcp-Storage-Pessoal-mac-gcs-fuse-service-account.json  mac-gcs-fuse ~/mac-gcs-fuse
```

And I got:

```
Using mount point: /Users/tiagogouvea/mac-gcs-fuse
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: setUpBucket: OpenBucket: Bad credentials for bucket "mac-gcs-fuse". Check the bucket name and your credentials.
```

I try export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` too but with same error.

What I'm missing? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to run by Google Compute Engine instance with scope storage-full configured, then Cloud Storage FUSE can use the Compute Engine built-in service account.

Have you tried with the primitive privileges of the bucket?

Are you sure that your .json file is accessible form the context that you are requesting them?

Comment: Thanks @mario for replying! 

1) I'm planning to use FUSE on my personal computer, to access some storage over a mounted point. I'm not planning to use on an Instance at this time.

3) The file is accessible, I even set a 777 to ensure that. :) 

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: 2) How about the "primitive privileges"? I don't know about this. I'm already logged on terminal with my gcloud account, that has access to the bucket, but when I call the gcsfuse without the --key-file I got the same error "Bad credentials for bucket mac-gcs-fuse". I exported the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on my terminal and it is there when I call "echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS".

Comment: I replicate your issue in Cloud Shell and everything works fine, due to implicit Service Account login. Did you find any special instruction for OS X?

Comment: The primitive roles are the basic roles for the bucket, like Write Read... Maybe you can try to isolate the problem and review if its a system issue , or a authorization issue. Im continue reading about the OS X specifications.

Comment: I created a new service account, allowing just read and write storage objects, downloaded the json file and tested again, and got the same error: Bad credentials for bucket "mac-gcs-fuse".
About the OSX, I already have a AWS storage using FUSE and works like expected.
I don't know what to try now.. :(

Comment: Try to assign the account as project owner, and re download the json file, in order to know if is a privileges issue.

Comment: Something really strange here. I created a new service-account, with read/write on storage, but, beeing the project owner, and, got the same error again: Bad credentials for bucket "mac-gcs-fuse". Check the bucket name and your credentials.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood, assign the role of project owner to the service account please.

Comment: I did it. Just created a new account, with read/write on storage, and owner on project.